# nodejs mysql queries showing only one records instead of all records in the database

Tags: mysql, node.js

Am trying to retrieve all the database records from  a table called **post** using node js but the problem is that only one record is retrieved instead of all.
In php I can use  **`while()`** loop to loop through the database record to get all data.

Currently, I do not know how to neatly loop through the database in nodejs to get all the records from database. Some Stackoverflow scholars suggest using await/async method but i do not know to to implement it on the code below to make it work. can someone help me fix the issue.

```
var connection = require('./config');
module.exports.getpost = function (req, res) {
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts', function (error, results, fields) {

        if (error) {
            console.log('error');
            res.json({
                status : false,
                message : 'there are some error with the query'

            });
        } else {
            var postid = results[0].id;
            var title = results[0].title;
            var content = results[0].content;
            var type = -1;
             console.log(title);

        // Checking user status
   connection.query('SELECT count(*) as cntStatus,type FROM like_table WHERE userid= ? and postid=?', [userid,postid], function (error, results, fields) {
         if (error) {
                    console.log('error');
                    res.json({
                        status : false,
                        message : 'there are some error with the query'

                    });
                } else {



                    var total_count = results[0].cntStatus;
 if(total_count > 0){
        type = results[0].type;

        }



                    var total_count = results[0].cntStatus;
                    var result = {



                        "id" : postid,
                        "title" : title,
                        "content" : content,
"type" : type,
"likes" : total_count
                    };

                    console.log('query okay');
                    res.json({
                        //data:results,
                        data : result

                    });
                }
            });
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**async waterfall** - Runs an array of functions in series, each passing their results to the next in the array. However, if any of the functions pass an error to the callback, the next function is not executed and the main callback is immediately called with the error.

```
var connection = require('./config');
var async = require('async');
module.exports.getpost = function (req, res) {
    var arrayOfFuncs = [];
    var func_1 = function(callback) {

        connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('error');
                callback(error, null); 
            } else {
                var toPass = {};
                toPass.postid = results[0].id;
                toPass.title = results[0].title;
                toPass.content = results[0].content;
                toPass.type = -1;
                callback(null, toPass); 
            }
        })
    }
    arrayOfFuncs.push(func_1);

    var func_2 = function(prevData, callback) {
        connection.query('SELECT count(*) as cntStatus,type FROM like_table WHERE userid= ? and postid=?', [userid,prevData.postid], function (error, results, fields) {
         if (error) {
                    console.log('error');
                    callback(error, null); 
                } else {
                    var total_count = results[0].cntStatus;
                    if(total_count > 0){
                        type = results[0].type;
                    }
                    var total_count = results[0].cntStatus;
                    var result = {
                        "id" : postid,
                        "title" : title,
                        "content" : content,
                        "type" : type,
                        "likes" : total_count
                    };
                    console.log('query okay');
                    callback(null, result); 
                }
            });
    }
    arrayOfFuncs.push(func_2);

    async.waterfall(arrayOfFuncs, function(errString, finalResult) {
        if(errString) {
            return res.send(errString);
        } else {
            return res.send(finalResult);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using mysql npm. In that case I'm not sure what is the problem in your case. Results param is an array of rows returned by your select statement. So you can use loop to iterate trough all the rows.

You don't actually need to use async/await (which doesn't have any advantage in terms of functionality but looks cleaner). But if you want to get rid of callbacks you need to wrap connection query into a promise or use mysql2 npm which has promise interface. Here is how you can iterate trough all the rows from your select using async/await instead of callback:

```
var connection = require('./config');
module.exports.getpost = async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const queryResult = await query('SELECT * FROM posts');
        queryResult.forEach(row => {
            console.log(row.title);
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error');
        res.json({
            status: false,
            message: 'there are some error with the query'
        });
    }
}
```

Please note that you need to use nodejs 8 to run the code with async/await.

Also you don't need to do another query inside of your posts query, you can merge those two using SQL join